# Find the count of unique values in all columns in a dataframe without including NA values (R)

Tags: r, dataframe, unique, distinct, missing-data

Given a reproducible dataframe, I want to find the number of unique values in each column not including missing (NA) values. Below code counts NA values, as a result the cardinality of `nat_country` column shows as 4 in `n_unique_values` dataframe (it is supposed to be 3). In python there exists `nunique()` function which does not take NA values into consideration. In r how can one achieve this?

```r
nat_country = c("United-States", "Germany", "United-States", "United-States", "United-States", "United-States", "Taiwan", NA)
age = c(14,15,45,78,96,58,25,36)
dat = data.frame(nat_country, age)
n_unique_values  = t(data.frame(apply(dat, 2, function(x) length(unique(x)))))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `dplyr::n_distinct` with `na.rm = T`:

```r
library(dplyr)
sapply(dat, n_distinct, na.rm = T)
#map_dbl(dat, n_distinct, na.rm = T)

#nat_country         age 
#          3           8
```

---

In base R, you can use `na.omit` as well:

```r
sapply(dat, \(x) length(unique(na.omit(x))))
#nat_country         age 
#          3           8
```

Comment: if using `tidyverse` consider using `map_dbl` over `sapply`

Answer (score 2):

We could use `map` or `map_dfr` with `n_distinct`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
dat %>% 
  map_dfr(., n_distinct, na.rm = TRUE)

 nat_country   age
        <int> <int>
1           3     8
```

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

dat %>% 
  map(., n_distinct, na.rm = TRUE) %>% 
  unlist()
```

```
nat_country         age 
          3           8
```

Answer (score 1):

In **base R** you can use `table`. It also has a parameter `useNA` if you want to change the default behavior.

```
sapply(dat, function(x) length(table(x)))
nat_country         age 
          3           8
```